# How to securely manage SSH passphrases via keychain?

Tags: terminal, password, keychain, ssh

Recently I had a long time mitigating possible risks occured due to malware I got on my Mac. Now I wiped the system and trying to figure out how to set up it in such way that when similar situation happens I won't worry about sensitive information being stolen.

So, my primarily concern right now is access to SSH keys. Currently I have my keys generated with passphrases, so if somebody gets access to my filesystem he won't be able to do anything with the key files. But, as I see, a very common solution is to store passphrases for those keys in Keychain.

I have added passphrases for my SSH keys to Keychain and now it seems that I don't need to enter login password nor passphrase when keys are being used.

Am I correct that while passphrases are stored in Keychain, anybody who was access to my shell is able to use them without being asked for passphrase, and, if so, why is such insecure solution is so widely recommended to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware that this setup is widely recommended. It is not the default setup provided by Apple, so it is something you must explicitly configure yourself.

And yes, if your system is set up so that you can log in from your computer without supplying a passphrase, then others who have access to your computer can do the same.

Note that any program cannot just get the passphrase from the Keychain. The Keychain must be opened first. This means that you must be logged on to the computer - i.e. you must know your user account password (or what you use to authenticate with your account). You cannot just login as a guest and then extract your keys from the keychain, nor can programs running in a different context just access your keychain.

In order to get a more secure setup, it is advisable to configure your system so that you need to authenticate each time - for example biometrically. I.e. if you set it up so that you need to use Touch-ID every time something needs to grab the information from Keychain - that's a good idea.

An easy way to get a setup like this is to use third-party software such as 1Password. You can find their guide for such a setup at [1Password SSH agent](https://developer.1password.com/docs/ssh/agent/#:%7E:text=The%201Password%20SSH%20agent%20uses,even%20leaves%20the%201Password%20app).

An even better idea is not to store passphrases for keys in the Secure Enclave. Instead generate the keys themselves in the Secure Enclave, so that it can perform cryptographic operations on your behalf without ever revealing the private key.

An easy way to set up this is to use the free and open-source software [Secretive](https://github.com/maxgoedjen/secretive).

A convenient way to get keys generated on a secure element, that is not tied to that specific computer, is to use a YubiKey or an equivalent product.

Comment: I was surprised because GitHub recommends this solution (https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) without mentioning that it may be not the best thing to do

Comment: Do you have any sources which are explaining how I can set up ssh-keys with Keychain in a way that I will be able to unlock them via Touch ID?

Comment: Well, in defense of GitHub: it’s not the best thing to do, but it’s definitely not the worst thing either. It is considerably better than not using keys at all, or using a key without a passphrase. The convenience of this option could convince some to choose a better option than what they would have done. Also note that GitHub on the same page has instructions for when you have a hardware security key (such as the YubiKey I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: @ArseniyKulikov I have added explanation on how to setup this in an easy, "graphical user interface only" way. In your case, I would start by looking at the "Secretive" app.

Comment: Thank you! But Secretive app is not able to work with keys generated externally and seem to not support key exporting. This is not really convenient :(

Comment: @ArseniyKulikov Well, you can call it inconvenient, but it is a major step in securing your system against exactly the scenario, you have described. If you can't export the keys, malware cannot copy them.

Comment: But the point of such setup is that nobody is able to take the keys unless he has password/biometry. So, exporting keys via password could have been reasonable and secure option

Comment: No, that’s not the point of such a setup. One of the main ideas of the Secure Enclave is that it is able to generate keys itself and perform cryptographic operations with that key. If you have malware on your system, it could potentially  copy your key after you unknowingly enter your password. This cannot happen if the key is not exportable.